# LTR Direction - office 2016

Tags: office365, office-2016

I want my office 2016 (English installation) will be always be in Left to Right Direction,***All My office software(Word,excel, Outlook ans so.. opens in Right-To-Left Direction***.

I tried to change from File->options->Advanced->Show Document content-> marked Left-to-Right view.
I also checked in office tools and my default language is English.

***Updateed 3.4.2017***
In excel I succeed with VBA command from the post: [LTR excel VBA](https://superuser.com/questions/378111/how-to-set-the-default-page-layout-from-rtl-to-ltr-in-excel-2010).
But in the rest of the office I didn't succeed.

In Word I succeed using save as new tamplet and use it as default templet.

On Outlook I didn't found any solution.

> As @SiHa mentioned Office takes localization settings from os -> I chnged localization settings and it didn't work.

Comment: From past experience, Office seems to want to take its localization settings from the OS despite application settings. Might be worth looking there too.

Comment: I tried this allso -> dosnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As @SiHa mentioned Office takes localization settings from os -> I chnged localization settings to English.

Then I:

1. Delete Office.
2. restart my PC.
3. install office.
4. Open Office (All What you need)
5. Works great.
6. Returned local setting to my language.

Thanks @SHIA